# Jump to parent class definition

Tags: python, vim

I'm coding Python in Vim with `jedi-vim` installed. Sometimes my classes are very long (particularly when I'm added tests to a `unittest.TestCase` class which can be thousands of lines long.)

If my cursor is inside a class definition, I'd like to know the name of the class I'm in. Here's an example:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def testA(self):
        print "does something"
    def testB(self):
        print "also does something"
          ^
          my cursor is here
```

When my cursor is somewhere within `testB`, I'd like to know (by jumping there or otherwise) what class `testB` is part of.

Is this possible? (Using `jedi-vim` or otherwise)

Comment: Try `[[`, the usual command for jumping back a number of sections. I can't find where, but I believe one of the configuration files for Python that ships with `vim` defines a section to start with a class definition.

Comment: It's `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`

Comment: @chepner Yes!! `[[` does it! Amazing. Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @romainl Thanks; I was just skimming for the `sections` option, but it turns out `python.vim` remaps `[[` using its own movement function.